# C code in C++ compiler

Tags: c++, casting, string-literals

I have following code, it's code from tomcrypto's manual and it won't work on MS VC++ 2008 EE. Any help? Also can I ask replace `char*` by `std::string` object?

```
int main(void)
{
hash_state md;
unsigned char *in = "hello world", out[16];
/* setup the hash */
md5_init(&md);
/* add the message */
md5_process(&md, in, strlen(in));
/* get the hash in out[0..15] */
md5_done(&md, out);
return 0;
}
```

Errors:

```
\main.cpp(7) : error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char [12]' to 'unsigned char *'
        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
.\main.cpp(11) : error C2664: 'strlen' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'unsigned char *' to 'const char *'
        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

EDIT: Now code looks like:

```
int main(void)
{
register_hash(&md5_desc);
hash_state md;
char* p = "hello wordl";
unsigned char *in = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(p);
char* out[16];
/* setup the hash */
md5_init(&md);
/* add the message */
md5_process(&md, const_cast<char*>(in), strlen(in));
/* get the hash in out[0..15] */
md5_done(&md, out);
return 0;
}
```

Errors:

```
\main.cpp(21) : error C2440: 'const_cast' : cannot convert from 'unsigned char *' to 'char *'
        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
.\main.cpp(21) : error C2664: 'strlen' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'unsigned char *' to 'const char *'
        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
.\main.cpp(23) : error C2664: 'md5_done' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char *[16]' to 'unsigned char *'
        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

Comment: yeah but strlen won't pass it so I did the same casting to strlen, program compiled but when I print out array it's shwoing memory adress not hash. I will probably use some c++ library.

Answer (score 4):

```
unsigned char *in = "hello world"
```

This is incorrect in C++:  `"hello world"` is a string literal and is of type `const char[12]`.  In C it is of type `char[12]`, but the `const` here doesn't matter because in C++ there is an implicit (but deprecated) conversion that allows a string literal to be converted to a `char*`.

The problem is that `char` and `unsigned char` are different types.  It doesn't matter whether `char` is unsigned; the three `char` types (`char`, `unsigned char`, and `signed char`) are all distinct and in C++ you cannot convert between pointers to those three types without a cast.

This works in C because in C you can convert any pointer-to-object type to any other pointer-to-object type without a cast.  That isn't the case in C++.

In C++ you would need to use:

```
// use the implicit conversion to 'char*' to cast away constness:
char* p = "hello world";

// explicitly cast to 'unsigned char*'
unsigned char* in = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(p);
```

The removal of constness is usually a bad idea since string literals are not modifiable, but sometimes it is necessary when dealing with legacy libraries that are not const-correct.

The conversion from `char*` to `unsigned char*` is safe because all objects can be treated as an array of `char`, `unsigned char`, or `signed char` in C++.

Comment: Even in C, `char[12]` converts to `char*`, and there is no implicit conversion `char*` to `unsigned char*`.

Comment: Kanze:  My understanding is that in C, most pointer conversions are implicit, e.g. `int* x = "hello";` is valid in C even though it is ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

`char` is a different type to `signed char` or `unsigned char`; string literals are always of type `(const) char *`; so you cannot assign them to a `(const) signed char *` or a `(const) unsigned char *`.  To fix this, remove the `unsigned` from line 4.

If your `md5_process()` function explicitly takes an `unsigned char *` as an argument, then you should perform a cast at that point:

```
md5_process(&md, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(in), strlen(in));
```

*[As others have said, you should really define `in` as `const char *in` as it's pointing to a string literal, but that is not the issue here.]*

Comment: @James: yes, indeed.  I'll reword my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try again:

```
int main(void)
{
register_hash(&md5_desc);
hash_state md;
const char* p = "hello wordl";
const unsigned char* in = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(p);
unsigned char out[16];
/* setup the hash */
md5_init(&md);
/* add the message */
md5_process(&md, in, strlen(p));
/* get the hash in out[0..15] */
md5_done(&md, out);
return 0;
}
```

Does this work?

Comment: won't work because md5_process takes a `const unsigned char*`

Comment: Sorry I meant a unsigned char*

Comment: `md5_process` takes `const unsigned char*`, see https://github.com/libtom/libtomcrypt/blob/master/src/headers/tomcrypt_hash.h

Answer (score 0):

This is because litteral strings are const in C++, while you initialize it with a non-const pointer:

```
const char* in = "hello world";
char * out[16];
```

However it might cause a problem if md5_process takes a non-const `char*`, in this case you'll have to cast to a non-const:

```
md5_process(&md, const_cast<char*>(in), strlen(in));
```

Comment: @damnit: what's the error? It would help to have the declaration of `md5_process` in your question

Comment: md5_process declaration:  md5_prcoess(hash_state *md,
const unsigned char *in,
unsigned long inlen);  Still error that it can't be casted

Comment: You don't need to cast away the const, but you have to cast `char` to `unsigned char` using `reinterpret_cast`. Here are the prototypes: https://github.com/libtom/libtomcrypt/blob/master/src/headers/tomcrypt_hash.h